# Custom post type not showing product image in buddypress activity

Tags: woocommerce, buddypress

I have created a custom post type 'product' but the product image is not showing up in buddypress activity alongside content when products are added from frontend. But works when I use the backend add product.

I am using wpuf to add product from frontend and now I tried other frontend plugin nothing seems to work.

Can anyone help me out. Am stranded. Am grateful.

Here is my code

```
add_post_type_support( 'product', 'buddypress-activity' );

function customize_page_tracking_args() {
// Check if the Activity component is active before using it.
if ( ! bp_is_active( 'activity' ) ) {
    return;
}

bp_activity_set_post_type_tracking_args( 'product', array(
     'component_id'             => 'activity',
    'action_id'                => 'new_product',
    'bp_activity_admin_filter' => __( 'Published a new badlee', 'custom-domain' ),
    'bp_activity_front_filter' => __( 'product', 'example' ),
    'contexts'                 => array( 'activity', 'member' ),
    'activity_comment'         => true,
    'bp_activity_new_post'     => __( '%1$s posted a new <a href="%2$s">product</a>', 'example' ),
    'position'                 => 100,
) );
}
add_action( 'init', 'customize_page_tracking_args', 1000 );

function record_cpt_activity_content_featured_image( $cpt ) {
if ( 'new_product' === $cpt['type'] ) {

    global $wpdb, $post, $bp;
    $theimg = wp_get_attachment_image_src(  get_post_thumbnail_id( bp_get_activity_secondary_item_id() ), 'large' );
    $cpt['content'] .= '<img src="' . $theimg[0] . '">';
}

return $cpt;
}
add_filter('bp_before_activity_add_parse_args', 'record_cpt_activity_content_featured_image');
```